# Exceeding limits of Twitter API Search,I have Used since id...But now am getting the Error Parameter Already Exist 

Tags: asp.net, twitter

```
public void search(TwitterSearchParameters tsp)
{
    int c = 1;    

    foreach (TwitterSearchResult tws in a.Search(tsp))
    {
        drTweet = dtTweets.NewRow();
        drTweet["profileimage"] = Convert.ToString(tws.ProfileImageUrl);
        drTweet["tweetdata"] = Convert.ToString(tws.Title);
        string wrdtext = Convert.ToString(tws.Title);
        drTweet["getid"] = tws.ID;                          
        drTweet["ct"] = c;
        dtTweets.Rows.Add(drTweet);
        myDataList.DataSource = dtTweets;
        myDataList.DataBind();                 
        sinci = TwitterSearchParameterNames.SinceID;

        if (c == 100)
        {
            tsp.Add(sinci, 100);
            search(tsp);
        }
        c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: When posting code, please highlight it and use the code `{}` button above the edit window

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have no idea how the Twitter API works, but I checked the documentation here: [Twitter Search API Method: search](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554756/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3a-search), and it says:

**Parameters**

- `rpp`: Optional. The number of tweets to return per page, up to a max of 100.

  Example: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=devo&rpp=15
- `page`: Optional. The page number (starting at 1) to return, up to a max of roughly 1500 results (based on rpp * page. Note: there are pagination limits.

  Example: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=devo&rpp=15&page=2

So, it looks to me as:

- You cannot get more than 100 items per request
- You have to issue multiple requests, selecting consecutive pages each time, up to the max of around 1500 in total (as per the documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Karlsen. Soon after you crawl the first page of results, note down the latest tweet id and in subsequent calls, set that in URL parameter max_id. This is to make sure, that you don't miss any tweets.

Save that id in your database and when you want new results, use this in the since_id parameter.